# API request is taking too long

Tags: node.js, api, node-modules

I'm trying to make an API request , save some values to my database then render an ejs file using the results stored in my database. The problem is the request is taking too long. So when i render the page my database still have nothing. How can i fix this? should i add a delay or something? I'm using NodeJs request module

```
        request(url, function(error, response, body){
            if(!error&&response.statusCode==200){
               var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
            }
            parsedData.forEach(function(element){
                Job.create({
                   //here I will save data to my DB
                }, function(err, newjob){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(newjob);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    Job.find({"location": { $regex: location, $options: 'i'}, "description": { $regex: description, $options: 'i'} }, function(err, jobs){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("jobs", {jobs:jobs});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API request may take some time ,
but you are not waiting for the insert to finish .

You can do something like this, with no extra packages:

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
  }

  let cb_counter = 0;
  parsedData.forEach(function (element) {
      Job.create({
          //here I will save data to my DB
      }, function (err, newjob) {
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
          } else {
              // another job inserted into db
              cb_counter++;
              // if we files done:
              if (cb_counter == parsedData.length){
                // now are are ready to find and render jobs
                // make sure res.render is in the scope , or pass it 
                // to the function
                findJobs(res);
              }
          }
      });
  });
});

function findJobs(res){
   Job.find({ "location": { $regex: location, $options: 'i' }, "description": { $regex: description, $options: 'i' } }, function (err, jobs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render("jobs", { jobs: jobs });
    }
  });
}
```

But I would suggest you use promises instead of callback,
it will make your code much readable.

try something like this:
and please verify with your library that you use if support promises

(most likely it does !)

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
       var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
   }

   let promises = [];
   parsedData.forEach(function (element) {
       promises.push(Job.create({
           //your data to db
       })) 
   });

   Promise
    .all(promises)
    .then(() => findJobs(res))
    .catch(err => {
       // handle error
    })
});

function findJobs(){
    Job.find({ 
        "location": { $regex: location, $options: 'i' }, 
        "description": { $regex: description, $options: 'i' } 
    }).then(jobs => {
        // usualy you should validate that jobs is not an empty array
        res.render("jobs", { jobs });
    }).catch(err => {
        // hadle error finding data
    });
}
```

Please consider how more readable the second example is .
You can read more about promises every where out there.
I would suggest start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Have fun :)